# Polygonize lines and retain attribute

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, polygonize

I need to apply Polygonize tool to several hundred shapefiles with Graphic Modeler tool. However, the Polygonize tool empties the attribute table - and I need to retain at least one of the attributes.

Is it possible to do in a Modeler?

Comment: You could try "join attributes by location", handing over the original attributes to the polygons. Can't tell you how much more computational effort that would be.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: Join attributes by location as proposed by @ErikLohmann should work for you. Please update your question with exactly what happened when you tried and it didn't work. It may be just an question of which geometry predicate to choose.